# Register ServletRequestListener from OSGi Bundle

Tags: osgi, servlet-3.0, osgi-bundle, servlet-listeners, jsr356

I have a JSR-356 (WebSocket API) code that is packaged in an OSGi bundle.  The servlet loads the code via Apache Felix if needed.

I want to register a ServletRequestListener, which I would normally put in the web descriptor:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>path.to.my.RequestListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

but since the bundle is not in the classpath that wouldn't work.

How can I register the ServletRequestListener?  I am thinking that maybe there would be a way with scanning for annotations but am not sure how to set that up.  My other concern is that many users disable the scanning to improve startup time.

The listener's job is to initialize HttpSession so that I can retrieve the ServletContext in the WebSocket handshake.  If there's a way to achieve that without the listener then that will work for me even better.

Comment: Can you describe your setup a bit better? You say the bundle is not in the classpath. How can a bundle by in the classpath. In OSGi there is also no single classpath.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider Right, I was just trying to clarify why web.xml wouldn't work.  I removed that statement to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be solved completely with specs. Pax web has websocket support. So maybe this can help you:

See [pax web websocket example](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/samples/websocket-jsr356/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/samples/websocket)

Comment: Thank you, but does it initialize the HttpSession for each request?  And if so, how?  That is my main goal here since I have everything working other than that.